# How to obtain workbook-scoped name?

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

In Excel, i have defined two names. Both have the same name, but different scope and value. One is scoped to a sheet, the other to the workbook.

[image]

I'm unable to retrieve the book-scoped name, either in a cell formula, or in VBA.

in VBA, the following returns the sheet-scoped name:
`ThisWorkbook.names("myName")`
[image]

in a cell, when i enter the following:
`=book.xlsb!myName`
Excel rewrites it as:
`Sheet1!myName`

How to retrieve the workbook scoped name, in a cell formula and/or VBA?

Comment: see my answer below

Comment: every possible answer would be more work, then just making your names unique... isn't there an option to change the name of one of them? normally, this "names" should be "unique" to avoid exactly such problems...

Comment: IMO, scoping should be sufficient to isolate the names. For example, names scoped to sheet1 and sheet2 will not conflict. In this case, there's scope overlap, so the more local scope takes precedence. However, if we explicitly qualify the reference with the book name or book object, then logically and intuitively, that should work. If not an actual bug, it's an illogical design compromise of Excel.

Comment: @DirkReichel: "every possible answer..."   What are the *other* possible answers? So far, only 1 given.

Comment: because you cannot do this without VBA and to my eye, writing a sub/function is more work than just making names unique, I do not need any code to prove it... but, unfortunately, you would not be able to avoid looping all names till you found the correct one... also to be working correct, it should be volatile (pretty well shown by Julian Kuchlbauer). Now all that just to have 1 name with multiple values? oh wait... sounds like an array... but unfortunately again, it isnt one... it is just not working this way :(

Comment: @DirkReichel, yes it see it is more work. Whether it's worth it depends on the benefit. Since you don't know my application, you don't have enough info to say it's not worth it. This thread is not asking "is it worth it", only asking **how to do it.** Let's plz stay on-topic......   `Volatile` is for custom worksheet fx-- i did not ask how to make a worksheet fx-- why do i need `Volatile`? This is not an array w diff values, it's a name with diff scopes. You mentioned "every possible answer", but you have not offered any. Just off-topic comments.

Comment: Theoretically, SO is only for direct code-related issues. Instead of showing what you really trying to do, you are just showing a behavior of excel and asking for changing that. You also have not showed anything of what you have tried. Then telling me that my comments are "off topic" with "you don't have enough info" and "you don't know the benefit". So what is your benefit? How does your application look like? This should be included in your question! Please see [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to avoid *off-topic*-comments.

Comment: Oh and as a bonus for you [MS-Help](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64) tells you that if the first sheet (index 1) has a defined name which is the same as one to workbook-scope, you cannot alter that by using the workbook name... just use a sheet without this name at index 1 (also can be hidden) and your `?ThisWorkbook.names("myName")` will print `"=Test"`. Also your `=book.xlsb!myName` will not be changed anymore. But I assume that this is off-topic again for some unknown reason I simply don't know...

Comment: *"SO is for code."--@DirkReichel* —My OP requests a code solution. *"just showing a behavior of excel"* —No, my OP requests a solution to a problem. *"not showed anything of what you have tried."* —False, i showed 2 things i tried. *"what is your benefit?"* Doesn't matter— OP is narrowly-scoped, as encouraged by How To Ask. *"if the first sheet (index 1) has a defined name which is the same as one to workbook-scope, you cannot alter that by using the workbook name"* —That's not "bonus"— THAT'S THE ANSWER. Thank you, Dirk! Please post as an answer so i can award! i'll use that helpdoc in future

Comment: @DirkReichel, follow-up: that's not quite the right answer, but it led me in the right direction. The correct answer is no "work" at all, and does not require any programming. Correct answer below (it's not the one that got the votes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This conflict only occurs with the **default first sheet** in a new workbook. The conflict does **not** occur with names defined on any other sheet.

If you rename the default 1st sheet, you'll still get the name conflict on that sheet-- it's *not about the sheet-name.*

You can delete the default 1st sheet, and the new-1st-sheet-used-to-be-2nd-sheet, will ***not*** have this issue. It's specific to the default 1st sheet in the new book.

If you never delete the default 1st sheet, then forevermore, on *that sheet,* the sheet-scoped defined name will override a book-scoped same-name.

Therefor, to **answer** the OP, the simplest, easiest way to obtain a book-scoped name when there's an identical sheet-scoped name, is to **not attempt it on the default 1st sheet.**

No VBA is needed.

Tested only on Excel 2010.

A comment and [Microsoft link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64) above led me to the answer. Thanks to that commenter.

Answer (score 2):

If you paste my code in a new Module, you can use this function within VBA and within Formulas, to obtain Names at Workbook-Scope:

```
Public Function §(ra As String)
Application.Volatile
Dim tName As Name
For Each tName In ThisWorkbook.Names
    If tName.Name = ra Then
        § = tName.RefersToRange.Value
        Exit Function
    End If
Next tName
End Function
```

Just use it with "=§("myRange")" in formulas or with §("myRange") in VBA.
Using §("Sheet1!myRange") obtains the sheet scope Name as well.

Comment: @DirkReichel learn something new every day, thanks for the comment.

Comment: @JulianKuchlbauer, very cool use of non-alpha function name! Why do you prefix Name with "t"? Thx

Comment: because declaring variables with taken names (like set variables (win64, version...) or porpertys (like name or value...) or types (like range or double)) can lead to temporary errors / reduced functionality of excel or may even **permanently** corrupt your workbook...

Comment: @DirkReichel, i understand the purpose of not using a reserved keyword. My question is, why "t", and not "o" or "x" or "n"?

Comment: Just as short for temp, but it doesnt matter, what  name they have, as long as their purpose is clear

Comment: Ah, ok, thx @JulianKuchlbauer. (Since Name is an object, i might call it oName). Thx again for codes! I will mark as answer, but waiting just a bit longer in case someone offers an alternate solution. thx!

Comment: @johnywhy i think the time of waiting is over :)

Comment: @JulianKuchlbauer, you're right. I posted the best answer, IMO. Sorry not yours!

Answer (score 0):

use this
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").range("myName").value

Comment: He wants the name in workbook scope, not the one in the sheets scope.